# how to disable html audio player playback speed

Tags: audio

I don't want to show playback speed in my audio
I use this method
**controlslist="nodownload noplaybackrate"**

```html
<audio id="recordedAudio" controls controlslist="nodownload noplaybackrate"
src="https://www.zapsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/sound-effects-61905/zapsplat_multimedia_alert_chime_short_musical_notification_cute_child_like_001_64918.mp3?_=1"></audio>
```